# Use json to read the file into a pandas data frame

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to read the file into a pandas data frame, but get an error:

ValueError: Mixing dicts with non-Series may lead to ambiguous ordering.

Here is my code:

```
%matplotlib inline

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import json

json_str = !cat data/commonTeamYears\?LeagueID\=00\&Season\=2018-19
json_obj = json.loads(json_str[0])
team=json.loads(json_str[0])
allteams=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(team)
```

That's I got for team:

```
{'resource': 'commonteamyears',
 'parameters': {'LeagueID': '00'},
 'resultSets': [{'name': 'TeamYears',
   'headers': ['LEAGUE_ID', 'TEAM_ID', 'MIN_YEAR', 'MAX_YEAR', 'ABBREVIATION'],
   'rowSet': [['00', 1610612737, '1949', '2019', 'ATL'],
    ['00', 1610612738, '1946', '2019', 'BOS'],
    ['00', 1610612740, '2002', '2019', 'NOP'],
    ['00', 1610612741, '1966', '2019', 'CHI'],
    ['00', 1610612742, '1980', '2019', 'DAL'],
    ['00', 1610612743, '1976', '2019', 'DEN'],
    ['00', 1610612745, '1967', '2019', 'HOU'],
    ['00', 1610612746, '1970', '2019', 'LAC'],
    ['00', 1610612747, '1948', '2019', 'LAL'],
    ['00', 1610612748, '1988', '2019', 'MIA'],
    ['00', 1610612749, '1968', '2019', 'MIL'],
    ...
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the JSON that's not an image?

Comment: Yes, I added the sample

Answer (score 0):

According to [pbpython](https://pbpython.com/pandas-list-dict.html) with `DataFrame.from_dict` function you are creating the dataframe in a column oriented manner. 
Try `DataFrame` default constructor with a row oriented approach.

```
allteams = pd.Dataframe(team)
```

Comment: I tried and got the same error.  ValueError: Mixing dicts with non-Series may lead to ambiguous ordering.